# SUM over column without using SUMMARIZE function

Tags: sum, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have created a DAX code using `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` which returns the correct value within a table but on a card visual and in the grand total it shows an incorrect value.

**DAX:**

```
ROS£PreviousYear = 
    IF (
    ISFILTERED('Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence]) || ISFILTERED('Calendar'[Calendar Financial Year]),
    CALCULATE ( 
        [ROS £ 2],
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Calendar Date])
    ),
    0
)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Is there a way I can get the correct sum for that previous year column without using the `SUMMARIZE` function?

Comment: What do you want it to show for the Total or the card? Both of these don't have a date context (unless you have applied a filter/slicer). For the Total, do you want a true total (eg  5.8M)? For the table, do you have a filter/slicer so that it's only showing those three dates?

Comment: I've filtered on a week commencing slicer which returns the 3 days 27th to 29th, what I need is the total in the card to actually show the correct total which should be `5,868.82`

Comment: What's the expression for `[ROS £ 2]`?

Comment: ROS £ 2 = 
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] ) = "IN STORE",
   DIVIDE( DIVIDE ( SUM ( 'Campaign Overview'[sales] ), [totalAverageBays]), DIVIDE([RangedDays],7)),
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] ) ),
        CALCULATE (
            DIVIDE( DIVIDE ( SUM ( 'Campaign Overview'[sales] ), [totalAverageBays] ), DIVIDE([RangedDays],7)),
            'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] = "IN STORE"),
        0
    )
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it would simply work for the Total but it seems other things are at play. As a test, try:

```
ROS£PreviousYear = 
  IF (
    ISFILTERED('Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence]) || 
    ISFILTERED('Calendar'[Calendar Financial Year]),
    
    SUMX(
      VALUES('Campaign Overview'[day_id]),
      CALCULATE ( 
        [ROS £ 2],
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Calendar Date])
      )
    ),
    
    0
  )
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I actually initially tried and it returns the same total  `2.52` for some reason

Comment: What's the expression for `[RangedDays]`? Can you share a sample PBIX?

Comment: Unfortunately the dax measures requires columns in the data model which have sensitive data so I wont be able to sanitize the file, but this is RangeDays: `IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Campaign Overview'[branch_type] ) = "ONLINE",
    0,
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Campaign Overview'[day_id] ),
        'Campaign Overview'[ranged_flag] = 1,
        ALLEXCEPT('Campaign Overview', 'Campaign Overview'[campaign], 'Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence], 'Campaign Overview'[day_id])
    )
)`

Comment: When I remove the `weeknumweekcommence` and `day_id` columns from the `ALLEXCEPT` thats when the numbers for `ROS£previous year` in the table shows `1.38`, `0.66` and `0.48` which makes `2.52`, so thats where that number is coming from, but i'm not sure how to solve that

Comment: Oh, that's where `[day_id]` is coming from, try the updated answer above.